# `tcolorbox` not working

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[centerlast]{caption2}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\def\toright#1{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\newcommand\mydotfill{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,colback=white]
        \textbf{Note:-} Integrating the canonical form, we get the
        solution as\\
        $\displaystyle u_\eta=h(\eta)$\\
        $\Longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle u=f(\xi)+\int h(\eta)d\eta=f(\xi)+g(\eta)$\\
        $\Longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle u=f(y-\frac{1}{3}x)+g(y-3x)$\\
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Why `tcolorbox` is not working here? It's also not working if I use `\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to compile to `dvi` and the to postscript? Otherwise, remove the `[dvips]` option to `graphics`... and it will just work™ with `pdflatex`.